# [Miglayout]adjust the size of the container to fit the total size of all components contained, with insets and gap

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

How can I use MigLayout so that after `pack()` I can see a `JFrame` with a proper size to hold all its children components, with borders, insets and gaps?? Now I see some elements cut off, leaving half of the size visible but half cut off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out how to guarantee the proper size of a Container according to the sum of size of all the contained components without hardcoding anything.

1. Create a `JPanel panel` as your working panel, instead of touching the `contentPane`. Just add it back to the `contentPane`. **Don't touch the `contentPane`, it is the key.**
2. Set the layout of `panel` without hardcoded row height, column width, etc. This may ruin the layout, because your hardcoded height may be lesser or more of it is needed, leaving some line with wrong size, and leave your last line/column half cut off.
3. Add your elements into `panel`. When adding them you can specify sizes.
4. Add `panel` back to `contentPane`: `getContentPane().add(panel);` We don't need to set the layout of `contentPane`.
5. At last, `pack()`, `setVisible(true)` as you wish. No need to `setSize()`, `setBounds()`, etc. **The insets and gaps will be handled automatically by MigLayout.** Viola!

A SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class InsetsAndBorder extends JFrame {
    public InsetsAndBorder() {
        begin();
    }

    private void begin() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 2 2 2 2, fillx, debug", "3[]3[]3[]3", "5[]5[]5[]5"));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("1");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("2");

        JButton button = new JButton("No way!");

        panel.add(label1, "cell 1 2, grow");

        panel.add(label2, "cell 2 2, grow");

        panel.add(button, "cell 0 1, grow");

        getContentPane().add(panel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                InsetsAndBorder frame = new InsetsAndBorder();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Note: SCCEE → SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example). A minor mistake. 2) Otherwise, everything else in the answer is good info. - Glad you got it sorted. :)

Comment: Thanks, I never get it right.... thanks for commenting Andrew, good day.

Comment: *"I never get it right...."* When it comes to getting the abbreviation right, I have an unfair advantage. I wrote the document. ;)